# jQuery disable selectors in all div

Tags: jquery

I need to children divs disable all his selectors. Like :hover :active. And it would be great if it work well in IE.

```
<div id = "parent">
    <div id ="child1"></div>
    <div id ="child2"></div>
    <div id ="child3"></div>
</div>
```

Thanks for your guidance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var child=$('#item').children();
child.unbind("hover");
});
```

Comment: the op wants to diasble all selectors

Comment: Thank you. 
It´s work, but if I this I want again "bind".
Like this, so it doesn´t work:

var child=$('#item').children();
child.bind("hover");

Comment: You need to use the mouseenter and mouseleave events (which .hover() uses) directly when binding with an object.

Comment: I have this code, but doesnt work...
var child = $('#item').children();
        child.bind("mouseenter mousedown", function () {
            this.bind("mousedown", true);
}

Comment: Beacuse I need to selector mousedown was again active.

Answer (score 0):

The Best way is to disable the childrens:

```
$("#parent").chlidren.attr("disabled",true);
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/Somnath_k/UkZqn/1/)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this if you want to act on all descendants at any level of nesting:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
     $('#parent').find('*').attr('disabled', true);
 });
```

or using the descendant selector:

```
$('#parent *').attr('disabled', true);
```